# App question timer shouldn't kick in until submission

Tags: bug, ios-app, rate-limiting

I attempted to ask a question using the iOS app, but it was rejected due to lack of a required tag. On adding the tag I found that I wasn't permitted to submit the question for another 60 seconds, even though this wasn't a new question.

Is this timer intentional, or should it not kick in for edits of questions not actually accepted by the site?

Comment: I blame API throttling - the API documentation all but screams "cache each call for one minute".

Comment: I'll look into this.  There may be a way to do some validation without hitting the API.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here was simply that we weren't doing validation on the client-side for this special meta behavior.  The API, however, does do the check, so you wind up posting to the API, failing its validation, and then being forced to wait a minute because of question throttling.

This is fixed now, so in the next build (**1.0.1.1+**), these tags will be checked on the client and you won't hit the API until you pass this validation.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue today - please check whether this is really fixed as you claim.

Comment: @Floris He is no longer a developer unfortunately :(

Comment: @nicael well I hope that the newly added bounty and my comment get the attention of the deb team back on to this.

Comment: @Floris Sure :)