# Submitting a question is blocked in case previous submit failed

Tags: bug, ios-app

When using the iOS app 1.2.0.140 submitting a question may fail when a user is trying to submit a question with the tag `ios-app` but without an associating tag like `bug` or `discussion`. However after that a timer of 1 minute is started and blocks the user from really submitting the question after the tag issue has been fixed. I guess the timer should only start in case the question has been submitted successfully in order to avoid question-spamming.

Comment: Yeah, downvoting a 3 year old and by now irrelevant question makes total sense, I voted to close it...

Comment: Why is this irrelevant now? Has this been fixed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, seems to be a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229977/app-question-timer-shouldnt-kick-in-until-submission