# Cannot answer protected question on iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, protected-questions

Question in point: [Does placing a lid on a pot affect the rate of boiling?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169193/26969).

I should have sufficient reputation to be allowed to answer - and I can, on the normal site. However when I view this question through the iOS app, the "answer" button does not appear for me - on two separate devices.

On other (unprotected) questions there is no problem. I don't recall noticing this behavior before...

And submitting this with just "iOS-app" and "bug-reports" tag generated an error. When I tried adding the "bug" tag and resubmitted I was told I could not submit my change for another 23 seconds. What gives?

Comment: Yup, reproduced here on MSE as well so it's not site specific. As for the "could not submit my change for another 23 seconds" it's by design, an API rate limiting that is not related to the bug.

Comment: Comment for the dev team: don't forget to ignore association bonus in case you will add a manual reputation check.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the response, and for confirming I have not gone completely nuts. I don't understand why "you did not use the right tag; add this one" forces me to wait before submitting the correctly formed question. If that is the design, the design is screwy; but I suppose that makes the second half of the question a "feature request related comment"...

Comment: No problem, as for "why" it's because the app submits the contents to the server for validation, hence bound to rate limiting. There is [existing bug report about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229977/app-question-timer-shouldnt-kick-in-until-submission), I've bumped it now with a bounty.

Comment: Related (Android, same issue): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242281/protected-question-does-not-show-add-an-answer-button?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.5.

The iOS app doesn't have direct information on user privileges so it was blindly checking for `(!closed && !locked && !protected)`.  I've added a field to the API that uses the same logic as the web for whether you can answer.

The app will be a little more optimistic than the web though, since `can_answer == NO` for sites you're not a member of and "Add an answer" is one of the mechanisms for joining a site.  The new logic is: `can_answer || (!closed && !locked && !protected)`

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up and explanation. Glad it will be fixed.