# Reviewing from mobile

Tags: discussion, support, review, mobile-web, mobile-app

I am under the impression that to review frrom mobile one can only go to the full site theme and review from it. Am I right? If so, is there any reason why there is no way of doing this from the app or mobile site? And if I'm wrong and there is such a way, which is it?

Comment: And I really wonder why, after hitting submit without the last two tags, I was forced to wait 40s before I could submit, with a "You cannot perform this action for ...s".

Comment: It's all about resources. Developing such a thing requires development time. Stack Exchange simply prefer to spend that time on other things that they deem more urgent. I don't think they are against it, just that it's somewhere in the To Do List. (and not near the top)

Comment: [mobile web request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available), [iOS app request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231492/are-the-review-queues-planned-for-the-ios-app).

Comment: As for the waiting after failed tags, it [might be fixed in the iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229977/app-question-timer-shouldnt-kick-in-until-submission), so it means you have the android app?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, Android app.

Comment: FWIW: the [tag:mobile-web] doesn't have a special review UI either, but the review pages have been made responsive meanwhile, so they're usable from mobile browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those features are not available in the app (iOS and Android) because the [Stack API version 2.2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) doesn't have endpoints for that.

The mobile apps use the API to do the things they need to do. So before they can even start implementing that on those native platforms, they also need to have a 2.3 or maybe even 3.0 version of the Stack API available that does expose a /review endpoint.

Given the nature of reviewing I don't expect this to be high on the feature list though but that is just speculation.