# Hitting the question rate limit on the iOS app shows incorrect error alerts

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Ask a question on a site you are rate limited on.
2. Attempt to ask a second question.
3. After submitting the question, observe the 40 minute limit error alert.
4. Submit the question again.
5. Observe a new error alert which states that I need to wait x seconds to submit my question.
6. After waiting a minute, the 40 minute error message appears again and the cycle continues.

I would expect to only see the rate limit error message when trying to ask a new question.

> [image: Error 1]
>
> [image: Error 2]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No bug here.

The one minute rate limit is a question throttling on the API side, as mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231491/152859).

In theory, the app might be able to "remember" that you're rate limited and show its local error, but not sure it's worth the efforts.